# How can I add array data in winform datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview

I generated `Personel[]` type array from `Biz.Bal.GetPersonelById("1")` but if I want to add winforms, I do that like below. Is there a simpler method? Like `GridView.dataSource=myArray`?

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form_init();
            Model.Personel[] list = new Model.Personel[0];

            list = Biz.BAL.GetPersonelByID("1");
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = list[0].ID;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = list[0].Ad;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = list[0].SoyAd;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = list[0].Maas;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = list[0].Departman;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use databindings: [Example here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/BindObjects02112007233926PM/BindObjects.aspx)